# ColdFusion - Capture Last Parameter

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

From my understanding `#CGI.PATH_INFO#` will grab my url path. But in my application I only want to grab the last parameter in my urls. So say I have the following urls:

- http://www.mysite.com/page.cfm?id=13213&var=23&htm
- http://www.mysite.com/page.cfm?id=232213&var=33&doc
- http://www.mysite.com/page.cfm?id=454543&var=64&xls

How can I grab the `htm`, `doc`, and `xls` from the url?

Comment: _"From my understanding `#CGI.PATH_INFO#` will grab my url path"_ - **not quite**. The path_info contains the additional path information after script_name and before the query_string. i.e.`/index.cfm` **`/this-bit-here`** `?query_string` - sometimes servers are incorrectly configured to include script_name (the /page.cfm part) with path_info. If you want the last parameter after the question mark then **you're dealing with the query string**, which is `cgi.query_string`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [ListLast](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_14.html) function

```
ListLast(cgi.query_string,'&')
```

Comment: This wont work - path_info doesn't contain the query string. Correct version is `ListLast(cgi.query_string,'&')`

Comment: Why don't you make that an answer, Peter, so Mike can tick it?

Comment: Is there a reason the URL is constructed that way vs. using a URL parameter like:

http://www.mysite.com/page.cfm?id=12321&var=23&extension=htm/doc/xls?

Much more easily accessible as a #url.extension# variable.

Comment: Adam: The fundamental part of Matt's answer (use ListLast) is fine, and I'd rather see a corrected answer. Decided to just go ahead and edit Matt's answer myself.

Comment: Ben: That's a query for the OP - i.e. it should go in the question comments, not here.

Comment: thanks everybody! this is how the application was built, I am just modifying it without having to re-code too much.